# Using Hyper-V, I can't get past the unlock drive

Tags: hyper-v, unlock

[image]

When I type my password, it only shows what is being typed in the top left and doesn't actually input the password

Answer (score 1):

You need to disable the "splash" screen. Once you power on, when it asks to choose the operating system (Ubuntu, Advanced, etc.) , press <kbd>E</kbd> . It will take you to another screen, remove the string `"splash"` from the line  which says something like `"quiet splash video="`...

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to boot without splash.

After the system boots up, to save this change, you need to modify the file  `/etc/default/grub`  and remove "splash" from the line beginning with `"GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="`.

Don't forget to do a

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: They can't do this if their drive is encrypted typically.

Comment: @tw: It's possible, but you have to boot from LiveUbuntu, mount the crypted hd (of course you need the valid pwd phrase) and make a chroot.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I reinstalled Ubuntu with Secure Boot disabled and not encrypting the drive

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It appears to occur if you set the VM's ram to 1024 (the default) and OS runs out of memory.

To fix: turn off the VM, go to settings and change the RAM under Memory to 2048.